# Parsing Complex XML and Extract Values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Given the following complex xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value>
            <struct>
               <member>
                  <name>resps</name>
                  <value>
                     <array>
                        <data>
                           <value>
                              <struct>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param0</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <struct>
                                          <member>
                                             <name>param1</name>
                                             <value>
                                                <int>12</int>
                                             </value>
                                          </member>
                                          <member>
                                             <name>param2</name>
                                             <value>
                                                <int>12</int>
                                             </value>
                                          </member>
                                       </struct>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param12</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <int>3143</int>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param3</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <int>207</int>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param4</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <int>4056</int>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param5</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <int>267</int>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                                 <member>
                                    <name>param6</name>
                                    <value>
                                       <double>1.290682</double>
                                    </value>
                                 </member>
                              </struct>
                           </value>
                        </data>
                     </array>
                  </value>
               </member>
               <member>
                  <name>errors</name>
                  <value>
                     <array>
                        <data />
                     </array>
                  </value>
               </member>
            </struct>
         </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I wish to parse this and get the key/values out that are crucial to me - this being param0 and param1 and so on and so forth.

I have attempted multiple approaches . From using xpath to get down to the necessary nodes , parsing to a `JObject` and interrogating it that way or simply keeping it as string and attempting to RegEx the items I need out. I have even gone as far as getting the innertext of the XML and attempting to extract the the text iterating over the different characters.

I am loathe to deserialize this to an object as well as that will just move the problem to a strongly typed form.

All of these methods feel very clunky and not maintainable. Im looking for advise or direction in the best way to handle/parse this data.

I am not able to change the data source at all .

Comment: Have a look at `XmlSerializer` which is IMHO best for deeply nested data-structures.

Comment: You have a multi level nest structure similar to a file system.  Just parsing the structure without keeping track of the layering you will loose lots of information.  To properly parse this file you need to use a recursive algorithm that maintains the layers.  If you have a file on your computer getting the date if was last changed will be useful, but you do not want to search your entire c:\ drive every  time you need to read the file.  You want to keep track of the folder(s).  With this xml file you can easily file the name and integer value, but it may also be important to know the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering - I was able to solve my problem by getting all the member nodes and ignoring the irrelevant ones that I don't require. The below code gives me a dictionary of all the values of interest to me. It certainly isn't elegant but gets the job done.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(response);
        var memberTags = doc.GetElementsByTagName("member");
        for (int i = 2; i < memberTags.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            responseDictionary.Add(memberTags[i].FirstChild.InnerText, memberTags[i].LastChild.InnerText);
        }
```

As you can see I am skipping the first few and ignoring the last one. Should the data ever change this would obviously break.